# Ubuntu 14.04 System Logging

Tags: ubuntu, logging

I've set up an Ubuntu 14.04 Server (from an Ubuntu 12.04 Server) but today I wanted to look in the `auth.log` but this file is not used. It seems that ´syslog´ was deleted.

How does Ubuntu 14.04 log? I need this for a server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

14.04 uses `rsyslog`. When I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 I had to change the owner of the logfiles in `/var/log` from `root` to `syslog`.

(In `/etc/rsyslog.conf` the owner is defined as

```
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
```

)

You should also take a look at `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` where it is defined which events are logged to which files. There is also a line for `/var/log/syslog`. Maybe it's commented out.

Comment: When I upgraded, `rsyslog` was not installed at all. `/var/log/syslog`, `auth.log`, etc. were not being updated. `apt-get install rsyslog` resolved the issue (and automatically updated ownership of those files the same way you suggest).

Answer (score 1):

I just performed a brand new install of Ubuntu 14.04 using the official server media.

Rsyslog was installed, and the `auth.log` a valid log file with the default configuration.  It is configured by the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

If you do not have an auth.log then I must assume you did one of the following:

- changed the config
- used a syslog daemon other than rsyslog
- used an Ubuntu installer that set different defaults.

Without knowing exactly what syslog daemon you are using it is difficult to tell.

If you are using rsyslog, then take a look at your `/etc/rsyslog.conf`, and any files in `/etc/rsyslog.d`.  See where the auth,authpriv.* messages are being logged to.

Comment: I was just doing the same install for this and something else.

Comment: I don't have the possibility to execute a new installation. Ihave checked the DPKG-Logs and ´klog´ and ´sysklogd´ have the ´rc´tag now and not the installed ´ii´tag. Can I install this packages on my server?

Answer (score 1):

If you find a final message like this in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Dec 29 19:27:32 host rsyslogd-2039: 
Could no open output pipe '/dev/xconsole': 
No such file or directory [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
```

then that is the culprit. It happens because the default version of `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (or at least an earlier version and kept in upgrades) expects you to use `/dev/xconsole` for error monitoring, but that's just not available in headless server environments.

To fix this, disable the corresponding section in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, making it look like this:

```
# daemon.*;mail.*;\
#        news.err;\
#        *.=debug;*.=info;\
#        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Then restart rsyslog (`sudo service rsyslog restart`) and logfiles should now work.

Source: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187748/107321) to AskUbuntu SE question "[Missing /dev/xconsole causes rsyslog to stop as well as all other services](https://askubuntu.com/q/108924/107321)".

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when installing a brand new Ubuntu 14.04 and enabling `fail2ban` for ssh logins.

Ubuntu 14.04 uses `rsyslog` with default user `syslog` and group `adm`. However, the `/var/log` directory has permissions `root:root 0755`, meaning rsyslog cannot create a new logfile in the directory, such as the `/var/log/auth.log` file.

There are multiple ways to solve this.

### Make `/var/log/` writeable for all users

```
sudo chmod 0777 /var/log
```

### Change owner/group of `/var/log`

```
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log
sudo chmod 0775 /var/log
```

### Touch `/var/log/auth.log` and change its owner/group to `syslog:adm`

```
sudo touch /var/log/auth.log
sudo chown syslog:syslog /var/log/auth.log
```

### Change user/group `rsyslog` runs as (discouraged)

```
editor /etc/rsyslog.conf
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup root
```