# Ubuntu + Postfix: Mail Log Missing

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, log-files, rsyslog

I've just installed postfix on my ubuntu server and am trying to debug why outgoing mails are not being sent. This led me to notice that the /var/log/mail.log file is missing. For that matter, there's nothing named mail* in my /var/log. I've tried the following to no avail:

- Create a mail.log and change owner+group to postfix
- Restart postfix and rsyslog
- Delete the dummy log and restart the services, then send a mail
- `sudo apt-get remove rsyslog` / `sudo apt-get install rsyslog`

Running `postconf syslog_facility` returns `syslog_facility = mail`

Any other ideas?

Comment: You'll want to check the syslog configuration file to find out where the mail facility is configured to log to.  I don't know if your version of ubuntu uses syslog or syslog-ng - but either way, there should be a configuration file for it.  "mail" in this case is the syslog facility (sort of like a type) that postfix is using.

Comment: He/she uses *rsyslog*, as stated. In all Ubuntu versions I know, default configuration includes *mail.log* and *mail.err* files. @tys, the simplest way can be to remove the entire rsyslog package **with all its config files** and reinstall it to reget defaults, then you can put your customizations in */etc/rsyslog.d/* again (if you have any).

Comment: yes i also tried that before. i'll update the question.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as a duplicate of the one where the poster found the answer. This will increase the likelihood of other people with the same problem finding that question and answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently, this was a permission issue for some strange reason. I tried the answers from this post below that sorted the issue.

[Ubuntu 14.04 System Logging](https://serverfault.com/questions/596558/ubuntu-14-04-system-logging)

```
sudo chown syslog:adm /var/log
sudo chmod 0775 /var/log

sudo service rsyslog restart
sudo service postfix restart
```

Not sure why the /var/log was locked to root when I've always been on Ubuntu 14.04 and not upgraded fom 12 where root would be default.

Comment: This worked in Ubuntu16 also, YOU'RE THE ONE!!!!!